# Exporting a PDF-file with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 application in which I'd like to export a html page to PDF-file, I use this code and it's works fine: [code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/260470/PDF-reporting-using-ASP-NET-MVC)

This code converts a html page to online PDF, I'd like to download directly the file.

How can I change this code to obtain this result?

Comment: Please post the relevant code. You should not expect people to go there and read the whole entire article.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a FileContentResult:

```
protected FileContentResult ViewPdf(string pageTitle, string viewName, object model)
{
    // Render the view html to a string.
    string htmlText = this.htmlViewRenderer.RenderViewToString(this, viewName, model);

    // Let the html be rendered into a PDF document through iTextSharp.
    byte[] buffer = standardPdfRenderer.Render(htmlText, pageTitle);

    // Return the PDF as a binary stream to the client.
    return File(buffer, "application/pdf","file.pdf");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Make it as an attachment and give it a filename when returning the result:

```
protected ActionResult ViewPdf(string pageTitle, string viewName, object model)
{
    // Render the view html to a string.
    string htmlText = this.htmlViewRenderer.RenderViewToString(this, viewName, model);

    // Let the html be rendered into a PDF document through iTextSharp.
    byte[] buffer = standardPdfRenderer.Render(htmlText, pageTitle);

    // Return the PDF as a binary stream to the client.
    return File(buffer, "application/pdf", "myfile.pdf");
}
```

What makes the file appear as attachment and popup the Save As dialog is the following line:

```
return File(buffer, "application/pdf", "myfile.pdf");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

This is for VB.NET (C# below)

```
    Public Function PDF() As FileResult
        Return File("../PDFFile.pdf", "application/pdf")
    End Function
```

In your action method. Where PDFFIle is your file name.

For C#

```
Public FileResult PDF(){
    return File("../PDFFile.pdf", "application/pdf");
}
```