# Is there any way to Export/print Power BI Report from MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, powerbi

Hi Need to Know is there any way to Export/print Power BI Report from MVC C#. Actually Our requirement is to download the embedded report which we are displaying into our website. We were able to integrate the report successfully but not able to export that into PDF.
I saw a print method in PowerBI Javascript SDK but it is not working and also there are no references for this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possibly duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470277/exporting-a-pdf-file-with-asp-net-mvc

Comment: This is not a duplicate since this is related to integrated Power BI Report in MVC. Please read the question carefully before tagging it as duplicate.

Comment: I didn't tag. Why I linked that is if you export MVC page to PDF, any contents will be exported as well, regardless of what it is. I may be wrong though.

Comment: @user5226582 Actually I wanted to have some references from where i can get an Idea if we can export or print power BI report which is integrated in a MVC solution since we are loading the report using the embedded Url inside an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

there is a documentation with the new power Bi embedded functionality have a look at the following link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/power-bi/developer/embedded/export-to
I did the same with .net framwerok 4.8 and i can successfully export in my app which is hosted on azure. Although with a standard free SKU it takes about 50 sec for one pdf page. but as you can see in the link this can be upgraded to make it faster.
The documentation on the link was a bit confusing to me first. I would suggest to make a service - Export Service - or something and then call the functions from your main controller. The client is the same as you use for your EmbedService.cs you can use the code from there. To get the pages you should use the power bi api which is in your imports. Hope i could help, i stuck around this topic and its so hard to get the right answers so i figured it out myself. If you have any further questions ask me.